# Using String.split inline to set CSS classes in the view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, string, split, slim-lang

In my model I have a field type `string` called `god_type`.

Example:

```
Ice,Fire

Ranged,Cannon

Fire,Ranged
```

I'm going to be using Isotope to filter these models based on their `god_type`.

I need the output HTML to look like:

```
<div class="item Fire Ranged">
</div>
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
#gods-list.isotope-container
  - for god in @gods
    .item class='#{god.god_type.split(",").each { |c| c }}'
      a href='#{god_path(god)}' class='god'
        img src='#{god.thumbnail.url(:thumb)}'
        h2= god.name
```

And the resulting HTML:

```
<div class="item ["Fire", "Ranged"]">
    ...
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: or `.item class='#{god.god_type.gsub(/\,/, " ")}'`

Comment: @Damien: Your second comment worked, please submit it as an answer.

Comment: Will do. You might also consider wrapping this in a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
.item class='#{god.god_type.gsub(/\,/, " ")}'
```

You could also wrap it in a method, within a decorator, or directly in the model, or even an application helper. Here's a general idea:

```
class God
  def god_type_classes
    god_type.gsub(/\,/, " ").downcase
  end
end

# your view

.item class='#{god.god_type_classes}'
```

Noticed I've used `.downcase` on the string. This is just to address standard CSS naming (should be `item fire ranged`).